# Best practices for container registration?

Tags: .net, ioc-container, containers, autofac

There seems to be two options for registering your classes in a container - explicitly (RegisterType().As) or auto-wiring (RegisterAssemblyTypes()). Both seems to have pretty significant disadvantages.

Registering explicitly means I get a god class that knows about every type in my module, and gets large and unwieldy pretty quickly.

Registering via auto-wiring risks mis-configuring dependencies such as multiple implementations of an interface (last registration wins) or registering too many types that you'll never resolve, or having to explicitly override registrations for e.g. lifetime concerns (some types are singletons, some aren't).

Is there a best practice that makes registration less painful/risky?

Cheers
Matt

Comment: Really good, well asked question.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe a middle ground is to add an attribute to classes that should be registered.  That attribute can take parameters to specify how it is registered, for instance the lifetime of the component.

This isn't hard to implement yourself.  If you do, you still have a main registration function, but it only needs to know what attributes to look for (and what DLLs to look in) rather than every component.

Comment: Good answer. This can be done fairly simply using the Where() and As() methods following RegisterAssemblyTypes(), or using the AutofacContrib.Attributed library. This approach has its drawbacks too (as they all do,) since it discourages using multiple configurations of the same component in a single application.

Comment: I like the suggestion, but I'm a little surprised that it's not something a bit more prescriptive. How do most people do registration? How do you balance the drawbacks of each approach?

Comment: I really don't know what most people do.  I started using attributes initially as that was what made sense to me, only later did I discover people using a master registration function (which is yuk) or autobinding (which doesn't feel explicit enough for me).

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked into using Autofac's moduling support?

In your bootstrapper or wherever you build your container, you simply register the modules in your application and then in each module you are registering your types. This makes it much easier to read and understand.

Comment: I find using modules to be a good solution to handle complexity. One module per assembly, and one module in the app pulling in all required assembly modules. Within each module one can use either explicit or by-convention registrations depending on what is best for that specific assembly.